# Visual Studio 2010 vs 2012 compile time performance and stability comparison for C++ users

Tags: c++, visual-studio

as a C++ user of VS 2010 SP1 Im often irritated :) by slow compile speed(on QC machine) and infamous"waiting for internal operation..." long (sometime long long aka infinite :( ) freezes.
So Im wondering:

1. what is the compile speed of VS 10 vs VS11(Im primarily  interested in Debug compile speed)
2. Is compiler more stable in VS11?

EDIT: I prefer real data for 1) instead of "feels much better" or  "looks the same"...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Visual C++ team has a blog post on exactly that subject.

Read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/05/24/10309971.aspx

According to their graphs, it is somewhat slower in a number of cases.

Comment: so dissppropriate... Im disappointing but it fits nicely with general feel of things regarding C++ and VS. :/